# getting error at "temparr.get(newindex) = arr.get(i);" this line in code //getting error in this line as it converting list to array help for this

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

getting error at "temparr.get(newindex) = arr.get(i);" this line in code  //getting error in this line as it converting list to array help for this

```
class Result {
        public static List<Integer> rotateLeft(int d, List<Integer> arr, int n) {
            // Write your code here
            List<Integer> temparr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int newindex = ((i + (n - d)) % n);
                // System.out.println(newindex);
                temparr.get(newindex) = arr.get(i); //getting error in this line as it 
                 converting list to array help for this 
            }
            return temparr;
}
}
```

Comment: "getting error" - when describing a problem on Stack Overflow, or in a bug report etc, *always* give details of the error. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions on writing a good SO question. But fundamentally, you can't assign to the result of a method call. Are you trying to set the value in `temparr`? If so, you want the `set` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should make sure you are using the right terms. You aren't converting a `List` into an array, but into an `ArrayList`. An `ArrayList` is called that, because it has random access like an array (and actually uses an array internally), but it's not an array.

Your code has two problems: *Java* (and in fact many programming languages) don't allow you use a method call on the left side of an [assignment statement](https://www.therevisionist.org/software-engineering/java/tutorials/assignment/) (`=`).

I'm guessing you want to assign the value of `arr.get(i)` to the index `newindex` of `temparr` (*), so you need to use the [`.set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#set(int,E)) method:

```
temparr.set(newindex, arr.get(i));
```

However this won't work either, yet. The `ArrayList` you have created has a size of 0 and thus can't have values assigned to indexes larger than 0. The way you are using the list you'll need to initialize it with `n` values (for example, `0` or `null`). This could be done, for example, with [`Collections.nCopies()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)):

```
List<Integer> temparr = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(n, 0));
```

(*) NB: "`temparr`" is a bad variable name. It's not an array, and all variables are "temp"orary. Use names that explicitly describe the content or purpose. In this case I'd suggest `rotatedList`.